# Adding subroutines affects performance of all other subroutines

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I have a workbook that contains three modules for a total of around 19,000 lines of code.

I added multiple buttons to run subroutines that have performed perfectly.

I added four new subroutines (all very short, maybe 200 lines total) to copy/paste data and build a graph.

As soon as I added those subroutines, ALL of the other subroutines began running exceptionally slow (went from 5-10 seconds to several minutes with some freezing Excel completely).

I have an idea for a workaround (turning Automatic Calculations off and on each time a routine is run) but I'm trying to understand WHY this is an issue.

Are there limits to the number of subroutines Excel can have on standby or could this be caused by a completely separate issue?

Comment: If you export and remove those new ones do the old ones speed back up?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I have multiple previous versions of the workbook saved that does not contain those subroutines and yes, they do operate much faster.

Comment: did one of the new modules include a sub that was based on an `Event`?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 All three modules already existed and worked fine. The only change was the addition of four buttons to the third module. Each button served to execute a short subroutine (copy and paste data for the first three buttons, fourth button built a graph off of the data that was copied/pasted).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Excel attempts to update the entire workbook each time a subroutine runs. The addition of the new subroutines pushed it over some unseen and unknown limit (unseen and unknown to me at least). This seemed to resolve it:

I added these three lines to the beginning of each subroutine:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

And I added these lines to the end of each subroutine:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

That prevents Excel from trying to update unnecessarily. It fixed the problem, but it doesn't explain why those final three subroutines pushed it over the limit.